# How to pass a custom directive attribute to custom directive child element in Angular 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently trying to pass a validation directive to a custom element directive. But I'm struggling to make it work since it should receive model as an input while I am using bind to controller.

I have to premise that I cannot upgrade to a more recent version of Angular, so 1.5 is the limitation, together with the fact I cannot edit validation directive.
I thought transclude would have helped but with directive attribute it looks not so promising.
What the following code should do is to validate vm.model on input element.

Here's the HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="myClass">
      <my-custom-directive data-placeholder="No text"
                           data-id="myModel.id"
                           data-model="myModel.text" 
                           not-editable-directive-attribute >
      </my-custom-directive>
    </div>
  </body>
```

And here the app.js:

```
var myTemplate = '<div class="myContainer">' +
  '<input class="myInput"' +
  '       ng-mousedown="$event.stopPropagation();"' +
  '       ng-show="vm.isFocused"' +
  '       ng-model="vm.model"' +
  '       ng-change="vm.onChange()"' +
  '       type="text">' +
  '<span ng-show="!vm.isFocused">{{vm.model}}</span>' +
  '<span ng-show="!vm.isFocused && !vm.model && vm.placeholder">{{vm.placeholder}}</span>' +
  '</div>';

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myModel = {
    id: 'test',
    text: 'this is text'
  };
});
```

```
app.directive('myCustomDirective', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: myTemplate,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: {
      id: '@',
      model: '=',
      onChange: '&',
      placeholder: '@'
    },
    scope: {},
    controller: angular.noop,
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var input = element.find('input')[0];
      var spans = Array.from(element.find('span'));

      var vm = scope.vm;
      vm.isFocused = false;

      vm.focus = function() {
        vm.isFocused = true;
        scope.$applyAsync(function() {
          $timeout(function() {
            input.focus();
            input.select();
          });
        });
      };

      spans.forEach(span => span.addEventListener('click', vm.focus));
    }
  };
}]);
```

```
app.directive('notEditableDirectiveAttribute', [function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.myCustomDirectiveAttribute = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (viewValue) {
          return viewValue.indexOf('e') < 0;
        }

        return false;
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

I've created a plunker to make it clearer:
http://plnkr.co/edit/auminr?p=preview

So clicking on span element i should be able to edit text and directive should validate it (in this specific case check if it contains letter "e").

Is it even possible or am I struggling against windmills?

Comment: When you remove the directive from custom component - it somewhat works, but throws errors. It would be easier to help if the plunkr worked up to that point. Also: I would suspect that the form validation directive should be applied to the input and that there should be a parent `form` https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Comment: Sorry, I've stripped away lot of code in the example and it looks I've removed too much. I've now fixed plunker app. Custom element directive should accept different kind of "already defined" validation. That's why I have to pass it this way. And, sad but true, there's no form and I'm not allowed to add any.

Comment: The `notEditableDirectiveAttribute` directive requires the `ng-model` controller. The element using it needs to include  an `ng-model` directive. For more see [AngularJS Error Reference - $compile:ctreq
Missing Required Controller](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/docs/error/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=notEditableDirectiveAttribute)

Comment: That's clear, but this way it won't validate input element. ng-invalid attribute will be added to parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to adding directives to templates based on component attributes is to use the function form of the template property:

```
<my-custom-directive data-placeholder="No text"
                     model="vm.data" 
                     custom="not-editable-directive-attribute" >
</my-custom-directive>
```

```
app.directive("myCustomDirective", function() {
    return {
        template: createTemplate,
        scope: {},
        //...
    });
    function createTemplate(tElem, tAttrs) {
        var placeholder = tAttrs.placeholder;
        var model = tAttrs.model;
        var custom = tAttrs.custom;
        return `
            <input placeholder=${placeholder}
                   ng-model=${model}
                   ${custom} />
        `;
    }
})
```

The `createTemplate` function copies attributes and used them in a template literal.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API - template](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-template-)
- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)